HandshakeException in Flutter: Unable to Get Local Issuer Certificate - App in production
I have a mobile app in production that is made with flutter and has ssl but sometimes it gives an error: HandShakeException: Hansshake error in client(OS Error Certiifcate_Verify_Failed: unable to get local issuer certificate(hanshake.cc393)).
This error only occurs on certain occasions and not always, normally it works fine but I don't know if it is my ssl or my app, my https code.
flutter code:
`  Future <List<dynamic>> MostrarMenuPrincipal() async{
    Map<String, String> headers = {
      'Content-Type':'application/json;charset=UTF-8',
      'Charset':'utf-8'
    };
   var Url= Uri.parse("http://......../MostrarMenuP.php"); 
   
    final response = await http.get((Url),headers: headers);
    return MenuPrincipalproductFromJson(response.body);
  }`

